# What are the consequences of converting the storage engine of a MySQL database from InnoDB to MyISAM and back (Drupal 7 specific)?

Tags: mysql, database, drupal-7, innodb, myisam

I'm in the process of upgrading a medium scale (200k+ users) [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) 6 CMS to Drupal 7. Data migration will be handled by using the [Migrate Module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate). Up to and including Drupal version 6, MyISAM was the default MySQL storage engine for the Drupal database. Since Drupal version 7, InnoDB is recommended. According to this, the migration classes I've developed have to migrate data from the old D6 MyISAM DB to the new D7 InnoDB DB.

I'm experiencing serious performance issues when I run the migration scripts: The migration of the 200k+ user profiles would take more than 20 hours on a "large" Amazon Web Services server instance, which has actually been optimized for this purpose. Such performance issues are not uncommon for migrations utilizing said migration module, as I've learned from reading the module's issues tracker. However, I've found a solution to increase the performance tenfold by converting the D7 DB from InnoDB to MyISAM.

Now here's the question: Since I'll have to run the D7 DB using the InnoDB storage engine once it will be used by the users again, I wonder whether it could mean any harm to the DB if I set the storage engine to MyISAM for the duration of the migration process and afterwards back to InnoDB?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What step exactly in the migration is taking those 20 hours? If it's the change of the storage engine, then you'd simply postpone that time wouldn't you?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For every data object to migrate - user objects in this case - a migration class, which inherits from the base migrate module, has to be developed in a separate module. This class must then be addressed and executed by the migration module (and associated helper modules). The migration process regarding this class is started by a shell command using the [drush module](http://drupal.org/project/drush). This procedure enables other installed modules to invoke hooks on the imported data during the migration process. It's not clear which subproces(ses) take that much time.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make that clear: The migration process doesn't work in situ. It doesn't alter the data in the D6 database nor the storage engine of said database. Two databases are given: Database A, holding the data of the D6 site and using MyISAM as storage engine, and database B, a fresh D7 site using InnoDB. The modules responsible for the migration process, are installed in the D7 site and pull the data, which is supposed to be migrated into the D7 site, from the D6 database. The storage engines of the two databases are not affected by the migration process.

Comment: So why do you think the whole thing will be quicker if you change the storage afterwards? That would definitely add additional time to the migration whereas I doubt that the migration will be much quicker if the target is MyISAM

Comment: It has already been proven that the migration is executed faster, @a_horse_with_no_name. If database A uses MyISAM, while database B uses InnoDB, about 100 records per minute are processed. If database B is set to use MyISAM instead, the throughput is increased to about 1100/minute. My question is, whether switching the target DB from InnoDB to MyISAM, and after the migration back to InnoDB, may cause any harm to the data, structure or indices of the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're seeing a very large performance difference between InnoDB and MyISAM, it's very likely that the reason is due to transactional guarantees that InnoDB is making. Setting the `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` variable to `0` during migration should allow you to achieve very good performance for the time of the migration, and you can then set it back to `1` after migration has completed.

It is safe to change on-the-fly; however you should note that if the server crashes while it is set to `0`, you may lose some committed transactions (but for your migration I'd guess that caveat is fine).

Comment: Thanks for your input, jeremy. I already had optimized the server for this process. Setting the 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit' variable to '0' was one of the settings I used to improve the MySQL-environment. The throughput was improved by 40% (from 70/minute to 100/minute). The breakthrough was achieved by setting the storage engine from InnoDB to MyISAM (over 1000/minute), which leads me to suspect that there may be an issue with the module's or even Drupal's routines to handle queries on InnodDB databases. My question is whether the changing of the storage engines may mess up my database.

Answer (score 0):

you can also change sync_binlog variable to 0 ant it can also increase the speed upto 20% and after migration you can set it back to 1.

but in between if there would be some power failure in between the process, you might lose some data.
but i think you are just migrating the data, then it will not take so much time and chances of power failure are very low.